# How do I superscript characters in a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIButton set up in the Nib file of my iOS app. I want to set the text of the button to an equation:

```
myUIButton.text = @"x^3 + x^2 + x^1 + k";
```

It would be really nice to allow for superscripts. How can I do that? Should I consider adding to the unicode values for the powers to obtain the respective superscript characters?

Answer (score 5):

Any Unicode character should work.  Did you try the following?

```
myUIButton.text = @"x\u00B3 + x\u00B2 + x\u00B9 + k";
```

[Here is a link for superscript Unicode values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)