# ios7 - how do I set uibutton title to superscript?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I have tried to use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407012/how-do-i-superscript-characters-in-a-uibutton) to create a UIButton that has a title of 2 squared.But I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

My code is virtually identical:

```
 if (button.tag == 200)
        [button setTitle: @"x\u00B3 + x\u00B2 + x\u00B9 + k" forState: UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt to have a label of 2². Why don't you simply use `@"2²"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refere **Unicode Charactor** it will make subscripts and superscripts

[Click for Unicode reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Here is an example,

[image]

for,

```
 x² - U+00Bx2 -> X\u00B2
 x³ - U+00Bx3 -> X\u00B3
 x⁶ - U+207x6 -> X\u2076
```

, etc.....

```
[button setTitle:@"X\u00B2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"X\u00B3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"X\u2076" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

like that...

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 6, you can supply a button's label as an`NSAttributedString`. The `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName` attribute name sets the superscript level (negative values give subscripts as well). Note that you need to import `CoreText/CTStringAttributes.h` to get it.

```
#import <CoreText/CTStringAttributes.h>

// ...

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"22"];

[attributedTitle addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];

[button setAttributedTitle:attributedTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you two approaches:

A) Use the character viewer to type in the superscript into an NSString literal.

The character viewers is normally next to the date in the menu bar.
Type the number you want into the search box. It will display under related characters the superscript version. Double click on that to insert.

If character viewer is not there, go to settings>Languages & Text>Input Sources and check "keyboard & character viewer"

B) Use an attributed string for the button label.

This is the general purpose solution for all formatting. It's more difficult but works for nearly everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the best results using a `NSAttributedString`.

1. Change font size for superscript text (using `NSFontAttributeName`).
2. Move superscript text up (using `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`).

Works for all types of fonts and all values of sub/superscript.

```
//input parameters
NSString *title = @"e";
NSString *superscript = @"x";
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f];

//our buffer
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

//just append the title and set its font
[attributedString appendString:title];        
NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, title.length);

[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:font
                         range:titleRange];

//append the superscript
[attributedString appendString:superscript];       
NSRange superscriptRange = NSMakeRange(title.length, superscript.length);

//start of the important code - change font and move baseline of the superscript
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:[font fontWithSize:(font.pointSize / 2.0f)] 
                         range:superscriptRange];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName 
                         value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(font.ascender / 2.0f)]
                         range:superscriptRange];
//end of the important code

[button setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Result:

[image: Superscript screen]

Comment: @DavidDelMonte This is pretty detailed already. If you don't understand this, study some examples of `NSAttributedString`. It will help you more than copy-pasting code.

Comment: when I started programming, a long time ago, I learned (was taught), that the best programmers were lazy. That is, we do not reinvent things, if we don't need to. So, thanks for the advice, here's some back at you:) My learning style is such that I learn a ton from copied code. More than any other method in fact. That's how I learned COBOL in the late 60s. And with the help of smart people here, and kids on YouTube who amaze me, I am learning all over again. It's great.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte Please, accept my apology. I have more experience with people who want to copy-paste code blindly, without understanding it. That's why avoid explaining the basics which are better explained somewhere else (I am lazy, too). I have updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: no apology needed Sulthan!! and many thanks for the snippet. I am studying it! DD +1

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use this code in place of `title`:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"foot\u00b2"];
```

This is working for me:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnOffer=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"foot\u00b2"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnOffer_clicked)];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:34.0/255.0f green:182.0/255.0f blue:226.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:btnOffer];
```

Comment: The question is about setting the title of a `UIButton`.

Comment: @rmaddy This code is valid for both UIButton and UIBarButtonItem. as the title is of type NSString.

Comment: 1) Why use a C-string instead of a plain old `@"...:` string? 2) It's best to post an answer in the context of the user's question. Setting the title of a `UIButton` is very different from setting up a `UIBarButtonItem`.